# FCM Firebase Angular

Tags: json, angular, firebase, import, service-worker

I have a question about FCM integration in an angular project.
So this is my service worker

```
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "domain",
    databaseURL: "url",
    projectId: "id",
    storageBucket: "bucket",
    messagingSenderId: "senderId",
    appId: "appId",
    measurementId: "measurementId"
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

I want this part of the code

```
{
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "domain",
    databaseURL: "url",
    projectId: "id",
    storageBucket: "bucket",
    messagingSenderId: "senderId",
    appId: "appId",
    measurementId: "measurementId"
}
```

be provided in a separate json file, and then imported to the service worker js file and then used in initializeApp method.
Javascript has only async ways of fetching a json file, is there a non async method.
Any tips and suggestions may help. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another firebase-options.js file in assets folder like this

```
const firebaseOptions =  {
    "apiKey": "apiKey",
    "authDomain": "domain",
    "databaseURL": "url",
    "projectId": "id",
    "storageBucket": "bucket",
    "messagingSenderId": "senderId",
    "appId": "appId",
    "measurementId": "measurement Id"
};
```

And then imported that script in the firebase-sw.js file like this

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-messaging.js');
importScripts('assets/firebase-options.js');

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseOptions);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

This was a kind-a workaround because I am not actually reading options from a json file but js file, but it did the thing.